# How to deal with this exterior wood ruins

Tags: wood, windows, humidity, primer, damage

When you see the exterior of the window it looks quite spoiled due to hot son and humidity and moisture during rainy season.

But interior of the window looks quite new.

This window wood was properly treated with primer , sheenlac sheen two times to make sure the quality doesn't fade away.

This is how the exterior of window looks like

[image]

This is how to interior of the same window looks like

[image]

Please find this window also

[image]

Basically as the windows and doors that are exposed to the sun has lost its sheen.

I'm just wondering, does it require immediate varnish and wood finishes.

or it's just matter of looks we can and redo this , whenever we can afford to do like after 3 years.

Someone please share their wisdom and insights.

FYI:

I will update this pics of the wood doors that are exposed to sun rays.

All the windows and doors have concrete shade , just mentioning.

Comment: For outdoor wood, I've always used a soar varnish. These have additional UV blocking agents, and if I remember correctly they are also more elastic, so they handle sunlight and weather better than mist varnishes. Even so they need to be sanded down and recoated periodically.

Comment: It might also behoove you to clean up the joint between wood and glass, and run a narrow bead of clear silicone caulk, to prevent water from getting in.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to caulk it. I'll have to find a brown color caulk probably so that it blends with the frame

Comment: Correcting typo above: Spar varnish, not "soar". Sorry.

Comment: I think that the urgency of making repairs depends on how much damage you're willing to tolerate looking at. If _you_ think it looks bad enough to repair/refinish _now_, then get on it. If you're willing to put up with the look, and possibly spend more money/time fixing it later, then put off the maintenance.

Comment: @FreeMan - Just wondering , Let's say if I postpone this project to 2 years , would the wood go bad ? I mean deteriorate ? where I have to replace or it's just the looks ?

Comment: What did it look like 2 years ago? The difference from then to now is most likely _roughly_ the rate of deterioration you'll experience over the next 2 years. Since none of us saw it 2 years ago, we can't answer that for you. Either do a proper repair now, or do a slap-dash, temporary repair now and do a proper repair in the future. If the issue is only that it's lost it's "sheen", then probably a new coat of finish (over a properly prepared surface - dozens of questions here address pre-paint prep work) is all that's necessary. _YOU_ decide when you do that.

Comment: @FreeMan - It was applied by process .. like preparaing the wood by cleaning then applying primer then sandpapering the primer then applying the stain like that..

Comment: I think better I do sooner , thanks but I wonder in such a short span of time .. it needs another round of application that's surprising